# Create the module to product name with image

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9.2.0 I have created the module to display the products

```
$arr_products = array();
$products = Mage::getModel("recentproducts/recentproducts")->getRecentProducts();

foreach ($products as $product) {

 $arr_products[] = array(
    'id' => $product->getId(),
    'name' => $product­>getName(),
    'url' => $product­>getProductUrl(),
  );
}

return $arr_products;
```

**Error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function getName()**

Any one please help to solve the error

Comment: please show full code.. cannot find the function getData()  in the code..

Comment: Hi i am new to magento this is the block folder file what file did u need

Comment: where you have wrote code  getData() i?

Comment: I am not written "getData" function i thing this default function

Comment: http://blog.decryptweb.com/product-id-and-product-name/

Comment: @AmitBera   Sorry the error is  Call to undefined function getName() i updated my qustion

Comment: `product­>getName(),` is missing a `-` so it reads `product­` "greater than" `getName(),` - and getName() is not a function.

Comment: @fschmengler Pls clear how to modified to code to get the product name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code seem to contain a typo as pointed out by @fschmengler in the comments.

The row:

```
    'name' => $product­>getName(),
```

What you really want is:

```
    'name' => $product->getName(),
```

The original typo makes the code tell PHP to compare $product with output of a function called getName() using greater than operator ">", (instead of calling the method getName() on the object $product which is what you want to do.)

That's why it says it can't find *function* getName().

Comment: Down voted AND marked as correct answer. Nice.